# Do create multi auth in Laravel 5.3 code like Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I need create new project with Laravel 5.4, for create multi auth in Laravel 5.3 in github is training. [URL](https://github.com/jayminpanchal/laravel-multiauth-demo)

Now, I need create multi auth with Laravel 5.4.

Can I use multi auth Laravel 5.3 codes?

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed on the auth logic that would effect that.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed to the Auth logic.

But if you are using a MySQL version older than 5.7.7 you will need to add the following code to your AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.4